# how can I turn recursion to a loop

Tags: javascript

I want to turn this recursion to loop, how can I do it??
I need to get the all name of the children, I did it in recursion, and I tried a lot of time to do it in loop, someone know how can I do it??

```
const Inode: INode = {
    name: 'a',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'b',
            children: []
        },
        {
            name: 'c',
            children: [{
                name: 'd',
                children: []
            },]
        },
        {
            name: 'e',
            children: []
        },
    ]
}
const getAllNamesByRecursion = (Inode: INode) => {
    console.log(Inode.name)
    Inode.children.forEach((child) => {
        if (Inode.children) {
            return getAllNamesByRecursion(child);
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: If the children are arbitrarily nested, then a loop version will be fairly difficult…

Comment: @deceze You can do it fairly easily by imitating recursion: a single loop and an array to represent the to-do stack. But at that point, why not just do it with recursion in the first place...

Comment: Please tag correctly. This is not [tag:javascript]. DId you mean to tag with [tag:typescript]? For it to be JavaScript, it cannot have type annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comment, recursion can be imitated. In fact, machine language does not have recursion, so when compiled, a recursive function is implemented in exactly the same way: jumps (implementing a loop) and stack. Here is the solution in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), as tagged.

```js
const inodes = {
  name: 'a',
  children: [
    { name: 'b', children: [] },
    {
      name: 'c',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'd',
          children: []
        },
      ],
    },
    { name: 'e', children: [] }
  ],
};

function collectWithRecursion(fn, node) {
  return [
    fn(node),
    ...(node.children ?? []).flatMap(node => collectWithRecursion(fn, node)),
  ];
}

function collectWithoutRecursion(fn, node) {
  // start with the top node in the stack
  const stack = [node];
  const result = [];
  // repeat until the whole stack is processed
  while (stack.length) {
    // get the next node from the stack and process it
    const node = stack.pop();
    result.push(fn(node));
    // if the node has children, add them to the stack
    if (node.children) {
      stack.push(...node.children.reverse());
    }
  }
  return result;
}


console.log("with recursion:", collectWithRecursion(node => node.name, inodes));
console.log("without recursion:", collectWithoutRecursion(node => node.name, inodes));
```

Answer (score -2):

i,m not sure if i get ur question, but i think this is what u want to achieve?
solution in js

```js
const Inode = {
        name: 'a',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'b',
                children: []
            },
            {
                name: 'c',
                children: [{
                    name: 'd',
                    children: []
                },]
            },
            {
                name: 'e',
                children: []
            },
        ]
    }
    const getAllNamesByRecursion = (node) => {
        if (node.children) {
          return node.children.map((child) => child.name)
        }
        return null
    }

    console.log(getAllNamesByRecursion(Inode))
```

Comment: i want get all of children's names, from all level' in my recursion it's working

Comment: I think u need to stringify it first then do a regex to search all name value, because if ur object became has deep nested, do a recursion will be no relevant or useless

Comment: how can I do it?